# How to evaluate the hadamard finite integrals

Tags: real-analysis, hadamard-product

Is there some analytical method to calculate the hadamard finite integral,
for example , $\int_0^1 |c-x|^{-\alpha} dx$, for $c \in (0,1)$ and alpha not integer, and $1<\alpha<2$. And is there any reference books about Hadamard finite part integrals?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Up to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization), we start from the calculation of the integral $$J(\alpha):=\int_0^1 \frac 1 {|c-x|^{\alpha-1}}dx=-{\frac {{c}^{2-\alpha}+ \left( 1-c \right) ^{-\alpha}{c}^{2}-2\,
 \left( 1-c \right) ^{-\alpha}c+ \left( 1-c \right) ^{-\alpha}}{\alpha
-2}}.
$$
Then we consider
$$\frac{J'(\alpha)} {1-\alpha}={\frac {{c}^{2-\alpha}+ \left( 1-c \right) ^{-\alpha}{c}^{2}-2\,
 \left( 1-c \right) ^{-\alpha}c+ \left( 1-c \right) ^{-\alpha}}{
 ( 1-\alpha) \left( \alpha-2 \right)   ^{2}}}-$$
 $${\frac {-{c}^{2-\alpha}\ln  \left( c \right) - \left( 1-c \right) ^{-
\alpha}\ln  \left( 1-c \right) {c}^{2}+2\, \left( 1-c \right) ^{-
\alpha}\ln  \left( 1-c \right) c- \left( 1-c \right) ^{-\alpha}\ln 
 \left( 1-c \right) }{(1-\alpha )\left( \alpha-2 \right) }}$$

$$
$$